# How to remove random characters attached to url with htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I've done a lot of searching and can't find out exactly how to do this. I have no experience with regex.

I have url's like this http://www.domain.com/funny-dog-video_234386b89.html

What I want is to remove these random strings that get added by the script like _234386b89 so that I end up with http://www.domain.com/funny-dog-video.html

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of them, but if you actually need those characters to serve up the page, removing them is going to do nothing but break all your pages.

Something like this at the top of your htaccess file would remove them:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)_[0-9a-f]+\.html$ /$1.html [L,R]
```